# apache Httpd.conf file configuration with spring url not working

Tags: java, spring, apache, httpd.conf, wildfly-8

I'm having spring application with url say http://localhost:8080/campaignApp/index.html

I want to make changes in httpd.conf file to set server alias but its not working in this particular case..

I tried following steps for jsp servlet app as follows and those are working fine

jsp-servlet application which has url say -> http://localhost:8080/shoppingApp/Main.jsp
I made changes in httpd.conf file as follows

```
Under /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

I made following changes

```
NameVirtualHost localhost:80
<VirtualHost localhost:80>
  ServerName myserver1.domain.co.in
  ServerAlias shoppings.domain.co.in  
  DirectoryIndex Main.jsp index.html index.html.var
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/shoppings.co.in
  ErrorLog logs/ussdserver1_error_log
  CustomLog logs/ussdserver1_access_log common
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyPass /shoppingApp http://localhost:8080/shoppingApp
  ProxyPassReverse /shoppingApp http://localhost:8080/shoppingApp
  ProxyTimeout 2400
</VirtualHost>
```

Now,

```
 under /var/www/html/shoppings.co.in/index.html
```

I made following changes

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0;url=/shoppingApp/Main.jsp">
<title>Index Redirect</title>
</head>
</body>
</html>
```

now,
when i hit url shoppings.domain.co.in it is bringing url as expected ,

```
i.e.  http://shoppings.domain.co.in/shoppingApp/Main.jsp
```

While same steps are not working when tried with spring app url.. 
Plz give me steps to bring that url up as

```
http://campaign.domain.co.in/campaignApp/index.html
```

I'm using wildfly8.2.1.final for both above applications